# Why can't I covert a string with a number into an integer?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    handling_cost = 5
    cost_per_item = 4.25
    prompt = "Enter number (5 - 20): "
    get_number(prompt)
    int(prompt)
    get_cost(prompt, cost_per_item, handling_cost)
    display_details(prompt, cost_per_item)
    

def get_number(prompt):
    return int(input(prompt))
def get_cost(number, cost_per_unit, handling_cost):
    total_cost = number * cost_per_unit + handling_cost
    return round(total_cost)
def display_details(items, cost_each, handling_cost, final_price):
    print("Items: ", items, " Cost per item: $", cost_each, sep="")
    print("Handling cost: $", handling_cost, sep="")
    print("Total $", final_price, sep="")
main()
```

Hi there,

I'm having trouble converting a string number into an integer.

On line 6 of my code, I try to convert the prompt into an integer so it can be converted into an integer and then multiplied in the get_cost function. But I get the error message shown below:

How do  I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing int() your prompt instead of the user inputted value. Just get rid of int(prompt) and change line 5 to user_val = get_number(prompt)

```
...
user_val = get_number(prompt)
get_cost(user_val, cost_per_item, handling_cost)
display_details(user_val, cost_per_item)
```

Comment: Ah I see I understand now. Just one more question, why did putting int in front of the string not work? Like if you go int("33") it'll convert the string number to an integer, right? Why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions! However, what you were doing on line 6 was int("Enter number (5-20):"), which is definitely not able to be converted into an integer. If you found the answer helpful please consider accepting it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may've confused things a little bit (or maybe it's me that didn't get it as you) but let's make things clear:

At line 4 you have:

```
prompt = "Enter number (5 - 20): "
```

So `prompt` is your string that the user will read and then input the value.

At line 5 you call the function that reads the value and casts it to int:

```
get_number(prompt)
```

The problem is that you are not assigning the value that this function returns to any variable, so you are losing the read value.

At line 6 you are trying to cast `prompt` to int, but it is a string (it contains the string that has been assigned to it at line 4)

So what you should do to fix it is to declare a variable at line 5 and assign to it the `` get_number`() `` call, like `value = get_number(prompt)`.

You then should have something like:

```
prompt = "Enter number (5 - 20): "
value = get_number(prompt)
```

And remember that at line 7 and 8 you are sending `prompt` as paremeter, but actually it should be your new `value` variable.

```
get_cost(value, cost_per_item, handling_cost)
display_details(value, cost_per_item)
```

Comment: Thanks very much I get what to do now. Just one more question, why did putting int in front of the string not work? Like if you go int("33") it'll convert the string number to an integer, right? Why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: @Kris because you were feeding the wrong string to `int`.